# r: get a every 20 minutes sequence

Tags: r, sequence

In R, I can get a day sequence with

```
seq(as.Date('2014/1/1'), as.Date('2014/12/31'), by='day')
```

how I can get a sequence every 20 minutes sequence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates don't have minutes, so you need to use one of the `POSIXt` classes.

```
> seq(as.POSIXct('2014-01-01'), by='20 min', length.out=2)
[1] "2014-01-01 00:00:00 CST" "2014-01-01 00:20:00 CST"
```

Comment: and how remove the time zone ?

Comment: `format(seq(as.POSIXct('2014-01-01'), by='20 min', length.out=2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @JuanPablo That "removes the timezone" by converting it from a datetime class to character. I doubt that's what you want. If you want a different timezone, specify it in your `as.POSIXct` call.